# visual studio code equivalent of python -i

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am looking for the equivalent of python -i in VScode.

That is, a way to open a terminal (or run in the included terminal) the program that is open, and use the program in the read-print-eval loop, being able to call functions and inspect variables freely.

I searched for this plugin without success.

I need it to be around as simple as pressing f5 and typing something. I want to use it to teach, and my students already have many difficulties with algorithms and coding. Also, easy instalation would be ideal. I am sorry for being that 'demanding', but classes are huge and the chance of getting everyone to do a procedure go down fast with the size of the procedure.

I would not mind creating such a utility myself, if someone will point me the way, and then uploading it to whatever 'store' VScode downloads its plugins from.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to just teach your students to use a debugger? A REPL is for *trying out code techniques*; if you want to *debug* a program you're developing, you really want a debugger.

Comment: we are developing small and simple funcions (a selectionSort, or a simple problem with queues) and I feel that, for that level of development (and their level of maturity with code) it is simpler to try with a repl than to write some testing code and debug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828744/visual-studio-code-interactive-python-console  Further, for your purpose, I recommend jupyter notebook. That's designed for this.

Comment: [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) works exactly this way. Your script is on the left and the REPL is on the right. When you launch the script, it executes it inside the REPL and you get access to every object that has been defined. Spyder can be slow and buggy, though. :-/